# change a color of chosen column after sorted(after click) with treeview

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I want to change a color of chosen column after sorted(after click). for example like in excel

[image]

How to do it ?

```
    def treeview_sort_column(tv, col, reverse):
        l = [(tv.set(k, col), k) for k in tv.get_children('')]
        l.sort(key=lambda t: t[0], reverse=reverse)
        #      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
        for index, (val, k) in enumerate(l):
            tv.move(k, '', index)
    
        tv.heading(col,
                   command=lambda: treeview_sort_column(tv, col, not reverse))
    
    root = Tk()
    columns = ('name', 'number',)
    treeview = ttk.Treeview(root, columns=columns, show='headings')
    for t in (('one', '1'), ('ten', '10'), ('eleven', '11'), ('two', '2'), ('three', '3')):
        treeview.insert('', END, values=(t[0],t[1]))
    treeview.pack()
    for col in columns:
        treeview.heading(col, text=col,
                         command=lambda c=col: treeview_sort_column(treeview, c, False))
    
    mainloop()
```